# Bold font issue with uarial package

Tags: fonts, bold

I am using `uarial` for typesetting my document in Arial, but I found that there's no bold font. How can I have a boldface font with the `uarial` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
 \begin{document}
 \textbf{sample data}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You did not provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). So I guess, you forgot to set the font encoding to “T1”, cf. Herbert’s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

foo \textbf{bar}

\end{document}
```