# How to revert the effect of a wrongly manually installed font?

Tags: fonts, packages

### What I did...

**First try.** The readme-file of uarial says actually, it should be installed in

```
 <texmf>/fonts/type1/...
```

I downloaded the TDS directory, uncompressed somewhere, and then tried to copy to carpets where the files should likely to be placed: e.g.

- `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/` but also
- `/usr/share/texmf/`

At that time, when I typed `kpsewhich uarial.sty`  that file was in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`. I compiled the code bellow, and I got no arial.

**Second try**. Then I installed the via "getnonfreefonts", and it says I have Arial istalled (not sure if it's the same as `uarial` though).

```
Installation directory: /home/<myself>/texmf
----------------------------------------
arial-urw      Arial (URW)                                  [installed]
[...]                                                       [installed]
webomints      Webomints (Galapagos Design Group)           [installed]
```

At that time `kpsewhich uarial.sty` said the file was located in `/home/<myself>/texmf/tex/latex/ua1/uarial.sty`. I compiled the code bellow, and I got no arial.

**Third attempt**. I installed [as here says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88424/15542), according to comments below. In short,

I located the tree with `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` (mine was `/usr/local/share/texmf/`, which surprisingly, it only had a `doc/` carpet) and unpacked there the content of the `arial.tds.zip`. I compiled the code bellow, and I got no arial.

I'm in Ubuntu 13.10 and installed the full latex package, if that says somehting.

---

### Status now.

**Question:**
My actual problem is that I want to use arial. So I tried to install `uarial` by some methods described below. I compile (with PDFLaTeX) following code, it renders no warning, no error whatsoever; but also no arial whatsoever.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}

\begin{document}

Text here, which should be in arial, but isn't.

\end{document}
```

How to revert following errors and do the right installation?

(If it helps to bound the problem, slightly changing the code into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

foo \textbf{bar}

\end{document}
```

which should work, as it comes from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98933/15542), for me doesn't work.)

Comment: Try installing with [`getnonfreefonts`](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/), which is already part of TeX Live.

Comment: @DG' Ok, I did it. Now I installed all the fonts. Does it work for PDFTeX? // Oh, nice, it corrected the path of `uarial.sty`, now it's in `...texmf/tex/latex/ua1/uarial.sty`, but it renders still the standard font.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Next time: [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423).

Comment: @JorgeCampos Clear out failed attempts from your personal `texmf` tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}

\begin{document}

This shouldn't be in arial because it is in the default document font, which is roman.

{\sffamily
Text here, which should be in arial because the package set the default sans family to arial.}

This isn't in arial again.

\sffamily

Now all is arial as the command isn't restricted by a group.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, how am I supposed to compile this? I mean, with PDFLaTeX it renders error messages (and doesn't generate a pdf-file). With LaTeX I get no .dvi. With XeLaTeX, no problem, but it renders no output.

Comment: @JorgeCampos If it doesn't compile, probably the font is not installed properly. But it is hard to say without knowing which error messages you get... By the way, my code is saying essentially the same thing as the code in the answer you linked to: `uarial.sty` only installs arial as the default *sans* family. You will still get regular Computer Modern or whatever for the roman/serif family (without changing the default family or switching to sans).

Comment: Well, the error is `[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1`, then says `0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes` but it generates no PDF. I get the same with this answer here. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140103/15542

Comment: Oh, I see. In on installing this time with `getnonfreefonts-sty` I only found an error regarding `arial`, i.e. "ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
 arial.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)

 Did you run mktexlsr?"

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the procedure is the same as under Windows. You should add this line in your `updmap.cfg`:

```
Map ua1.map
```

then run (perhaps texhash, and)`updmap-sys` in order to redo the psfonts database.

The right place to unzip your tds.zip file as far as I know is your `local-texmf`, which is created by TeX Live on installation. What the readme file says actually is that it should be placed right under a texmf root. With TeX Live, you have `texmf-dist` where the files from the official TeX Live distribution are put, and `texmf-local`(or so…) where your should put files you install yourself. This way, they do not risk to be overwritten on a TeX Live update.

Comment: The “local tree” location can be found by doing `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`

Comment: Don't use `updmap`. Use `updmap-sys`.

Comment: @cfr: Ah! That's one of the slight differences with MiKTeX… Thanks, I change that in may answer.

Comment: Hmmm, once again: [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423).

Comment: @Speravir I actually tried now with your answer's procedure. I find now the `.sty`-file in `/home/<myself>/texmf/tex/latex/ua1/uarial.sty`, which woudn't be a problem if I would get arial in my document. But the code above renderes no errors and no arial. I've tried with [this slightly changed code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98933/15542), and it renders "finished with exit code 1" and no PDF.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Get rid of the stuff in your personal `texmf` tree which has to do with `uarial` and run `getnonfreefonts` (with sudo or as root) to install it. This will be a lot easier as everything will be done automatically - you just will be asked which fonts you want installed so you can select them. The rest is magic ;). But make sure you clear out failed attempts at installation first to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: @cfr ok, I first got rid of all in the personal `texmf` carpet. I verified with `getnonfreefonts -l` unti I got that no font was installed. Then I ran `getnonfreefonts -a` (with `sudo`) but it's automatically creating a new `texmf` carpet with the fonts and all the stuff there. I don't know how to create that in `usr/local/share/texmf/`, where I guess it is supposed to be installed.